# Is this wall removal safe?

Tags: beam, load

I have a handyman here doing renovations. I had him remove a wall from a load bearing area. I told him we need an additional beam,. He insisted upon insisted we don’t.

He removed the wall and the last stud he removed, I saw the ceiling bow slightly. I am entirely freaked out so to speak. He keeps assuring me it’s safe. Is this safe? The wall he cut open spans 8’ roughly.

[image]

Comment: Would put the studs back in, you did not cut them I hope.  If the top has bent down a bit and it is too tight to fit the studs, a big hammer can usually adjust the height.  Real load bearing walls should not be removed without a plan from an structural engineer or at least an experience builder.

Comment: What is above that wall? What is that wall holding up? Your wall may bend a little now, but it could fail when it starts snowing. Make sure you understand what the wall is doing.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Especially those of you who came off less judgmental, that’s greatly appreciated.

@LeeSam, there’s no snow here, I’m in Florida but point taken, respected and understood for sure. This beam backs up to a cinderblock wall, it is at the end of the home, there is a closed in carport on the other side of the block wall but the beam does not extend there. I did replace the studs for time being, peace of mind. Going to place 4x4 posts for support tomorrow. Thank you again!

Comment: What's a "load bearing area"?

Comment: There's nowhere near enough information here to answer. We'd need both roof framing and footing layouts, at least.

Answer (score 7):

No one here can tell you it's safe. That has to be done by a structural engineer doing a site visit and examining the building plans. If you're terrified, go to your home store and rent a few ceiling jacks to support it until you're convinced it's safe.